# I am having issues with the donuts icing clipping through the donut on blender

Tags: modeling

[image]
there are strange dark lines appearing in the whole of my donut i think it might be something to do with my icing clipping with the donut. I am not quite sure what is causing the problem as I am new to blender.
The lines I am talking about are those strange black lines around the whole of my donut, This wasn't happening on blender gurus donut and i think i am doing something wrong. heres the blend file. [image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE. It's difficult to tell what the problem is from this single screenshot. Would you mind editing your question and adding a link to your .blend file? https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: OK I will sorry to be confusing.

Comment: No problem at all! I've added an answer that I hope will be of some use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to BSE,

I downloaded and opened your .blend file. Without making any changes, I am not seeing the problem you are describing:

[image]

I have not watched the donut tutorial, and even if I had I wouldn't know where in the tutorial you have reached.
I do however have some advice you might find useful.

Firstly, you might find it easier to apply some colors to your donut/icing while you are working on them. This will make it easier to tell which object is which. Later in the tutorial you will make proper materials for the final render; this is just temporary.

There are two ways to do this:

**Random colors**

In the Viewport Shading drop-down menu, change the Color from **Material** to **Random**:

[image]

**Specific colors**

- Select your Icing object
- Open the Materials panel and add a new material to the Icing object

[image]

- Scroll down and expand the Viewport Display section. Select a color for your Icing **in the Viewport**.

[image]

- Repeat these steps with the donut. Your Viewport should now look something like this:

[image]

[image]

Please note that these colors will **not affect your render**. They will only be shown in Solid Shading mode in the Viewport.

This make it easier to see which object is which while working on them.

I've noticed that some of the edges on your donut are **Marked Sharp**:
These edges should not be sharp (a donut has no sharp edges!).

[image]

To remove the sharp edges:

- Select the donut and press Tab to enter Edit mode
- Press A to select all vertices
- Press CTRL+E and use the Clear Sharp option

Although I am not seeing your problem when I open your .blend file, I would guess this problem is due to parts of your donut clipping through the icing.

For example, the verts I have highlighted here:

[image]

You could correct this by add some additional thickness to the solidy modifier on the Icing object:

[image]

You might also want to adjust your icing mesh in certain places so it is attached to the donut. For example, this part of the icing looks a bit odd:

[image]

(From the bottom):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help i didn't realise my icing was looking so weird in the middle thanks for all the tips as well.

Comment: Don't mention it :) Would you mind accepting my answer to make it easier for others to find it?

Comment: Done sorry for taking a while